# Prolog bind variable to opposite of another boolean variable

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I want to create a clause that will hold if its two boolean parameters are equal and the third parameter is 1 *or* its two boolean parameters are not equal and the third parameter is 0. My first attempt:

```
equal_bools(X, Y, N) :-
    X = Y,
    N=1.
equal_bools(X, Y, N) :-
    \+ X = Y,
    N=0.
```

This seems to work:

```
?- equal_bools(true, true, 0).
false.

?- equal_bools(true, true, 1).
true.

?- equal_bools(true, false, 0).
true.

?- equal_bools(true, false, 1).
false.
```

The problem is, I really need Y to be bound to the correct value. For example, `equal_bools(false, Y, 0).` should give back `Y = true .`. Instead:

```
?- equal_bools(false, Y, 0).
false.
```

It seems `\+ X = Y` checks for equality, but doesn't bind `X` or `Y` to any values. How do I fix this? This is for learning purposes, so I'd like to understand exactly how to do this rather than get a built-in clause that does all this or another library.

Comment: See tag for `dif/2` [tag:prolog-dif].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicely deterministic (i.e. no unwanted choicepoints), using (as usual) first-argument indexing, and unification:

```
bool_opp(true, false).
bool_opp(false, true).

% Unifies X with Y
bools_int(1, X, X) :-
    bool_opp(X, _).
bools_int(0, X, Y) :-
    bool_opp(X, Y).
```

Results in swi-prolog:

```
?- bools_int(I, X, Y).
I = 1,
X = Y, Y = true ;
I = 1,
X = Y, Y = false ;
I = 0,
X = true,
Y = false ;
I = 0,
X = false,
Y = true.

?- bools_int(1, X, Y).
X = Y, Y = true ;
X = Y, Y = false.

?- bools_int(0, X, Y).
X = true,
Y = false ;
X = false,
Y = true.

?- bools_int(0, X, true).
X = false.

?- bools_int(1, X, true).
X = true.

?- bools_int(1, X, false).
X = false.

?- bools_int(0, X, false).
X = true.

?- bools_int(I, X, false).
I = 1,
X = false ;
I = 0,
X = true.
```

Comment: Very nice, really helps me understand

Answer (score 2):

Prolog uses the principle of negation as failure. This means that a negation succeeds if it is not possible to make the negated thing true.

In this case it is possible to make `false = Y` true, by unifying `Y` to `false` (in other languages you would say to assign `Y` the value `false`). So `\+ X = Y` can *never* be true when either X or Y or both are (unbound) variables.

To put it another way: Prolog does not try to find a value for `Y` to make the negation true, instead it checks if it is possible to make the equality true, and if it is possible then the negation is false.

Furthermore Prolog does not have booleans as a data type. You can see the list of types at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=typetest, boolean is not one of them. `true` and `false` are just atoms, like `abc`. Therefore Prolog does not do any boolean logic with `true` and `false`, like *(not true) equals false* or anything like that.

If you want to implement this you need to provide the boolean logic yourself, for example as follows:

```
reverse_bool(true, false).
reverse_bool(false, true).

equal_bools(X, X, 1).
equal_bools(X, Y, 0) :-
    reverse_bool(X, Y).
```

Note that I simplified the case of N = 1 by turning the rule into a fact with the equality of X and Y expressed by using the same variable X and putting N = 1 as a constant in the third argument. Similarly N = 0 is expressed as a constant in the rule for when X is not equal to Y.

Comment: `equal_bools(X, X, 1).` would not unify X with `true` or `false`.

Comment: @brebs that is correct, it only unifies if one of the arguments is provided. This is also the case for OPs code though, and given their test cases I assume that indeed one or both of the values are known, allowing for the short implementation in my answer. But I agree that your own answer is more general and rather elegant.

Comment: Really helpful, particularly your comment, "Prolog does not try to find a value for Y to make the negation true, instead it checks if it is possible to make the equality true, and if it is possible then the negation is false." Thank you! Though I credited @brebs with the answer because I do in fact need to be able to unify `X`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to achieve the desired result is as follows:

```
equal_bools(false, false, 1).
equal_bools(false, true,  0).
equal_bools(true,  false, 0).
equal_bools(true,  true,  1).
```

Comment: Leaves unwanted choicepoints, with e.g. `equal_bools(false, Y, 1).`

Comment: @brebs I know that, but obviously this is not a strictly necessary requirement for the correctness of the predicate definition.

Comment: I agree, this is the simplest. I like it. For purposes of my Prolog education, I went with @brebs answer. But I think in production code, I'd probably use this one.